# what event fires when hit enter in select2 angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angularjs-select2

I am trying to add new element to array when user has typed its name and hit enter like in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m1SQXUxftBLQtitng1f0?p=preview) at the **Tagging without multiple** section. Here is what I've got so far:

```
<ui-select tagging="catTransform" on-select="addCategory()" ng-model="category.selected" theme="bootstrap" style="width: 600px;" title="Choose a category">
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Выберите категорию...">{{category.name}}</ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="category in categories | filter: {name: $select.search}">
        <div ng-bind-html="category.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
$scope.category = {}

$scope.categories =
  [
    {name: 'Food', id: 5},
    {name: 'transport', id: 10}
  ]
$scope.catTransform = (name) ->
  cat = {name: name, id: null}

$scope.addCategory  = (item, model) ->
  $scope.categories.push item
  model = item
```

Now as you can see `categories` are not plain strings but array of objects, so I have this `catTransform` function to make objects from strings. In the plunker when you type some random string and hit enter new tag is created and becomes selected at once. I couldn't find any code that would attach listeners to any kind of events in the plunker, it works magically somehow. 
In [the docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select) it's said the directive provides two custom events on-remove and on-select. I tried to attach my listener to on-select as you can see in markup above but  with no luck of course. So how it's supposed to be done? Should I listen to `key-press` and inside of handler check what key was pressed and if it was `Enter` key then add new category to array? If so, how can I get hold of current search string?

Also am I right that as the second parameter to the handler function is passed model of the directive (the same that I specify via `ng-model` in markup above) and if I want my new object to be choosen I must simply assign it like this:

```
model = item
```

I find documentation to angularjs/select2 is very poor I must say.